# Eigenvectors for the sum of two symmetric matrices

Tags: pca, covariance, matrix-decomposition

$R = S + xx^t$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $R$ and $S$ are $n \times n$ covariance matrices.

Is there anything I can say about the eigenvectors of $R$ and $S$?  Or at least the largest eigenvalue and eigenvector pair of R?

Is there a way to express the eigenvectors of $R$ in terms of $S$ and $x$?

Comment: The sum of two covariance matrices is positive semidefinite; the eigenvalues are non-negative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rank one matrix $x x^t$ has a single nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda=|x|^2$, with $x$ itself as eigenvector, because $ (x x^t) x = |x|^2 x$.

Now, unless $x$ happens to be an eigenvector of $S$, I dont' think  you can say anything about the eigenvectors of $R$.

Regarding the largest eigenvalue of $R$ (I guess  you meant eigenvalue instead of eigenvector?), recall that

$$\lambda^{max}_R = max_{|w|=1} ( w^T R w)$$

but $$ w^T R w =  w^T S w + w^T x x^t w  \le \lambda^{max}_S + |x|^2$$

Further, calling $w_S$  the normalized eigenvector associated to $\lambda^{max}_S$, we have

$$max_{|w|=1} ( w^T R w) \ge w_S^T R w_S  =  w_S^T S w_S + w_S^T x x^t w_S = \lambda^{max}_S +  w_S^T x x^t w_S \ge \lambda^{max}_S $$

becase $w^T x x^t w \ge 0$ $\forall w$

Hence, I think that's about the only thing you can assert:

$$ \lambda^{max}_S  \le \lambda^{max}_R \le \lambda^{max}_S + |x|^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the great response.  I understand that you can assert the upper bound because $w^t$ is maximized for $R$ and not necessarily for $S$, but how did you get to the lower bound $$ \lambda^{max}_S  \le \lambda^{max}_R$$

Comment: "but how did you get to the lower bound?" From the same equation. I added a explanation.